# How to access to pointer to pixels of a QWidget

Tags: c++, performance, qt, widget, pixel

I want to continuously update pixels of a QWidget.

For this I need to access to raw pointer to pixels of a QWidget.

I already know about painting line and etc, but those aren't very well and efficient for my work.

Comment: It seems to me it is a XY problem. What do you want to do ?

Comment: Why do you think it is XY whatever? I'm asking clearly, how can i access to such data.

Comment: I just ask more information: what are you trying to really do?

Comment: I'm calculating something on the pixels of a widget, and I want to visualize them.

Comment: Why do you not use some QImage? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html

Comment: because I want to allow the user resize the widget continuously, and also some other performance stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113306/discussion-between-boiethios-and-hossein-noroozpour).

Comment: You cannot access the already rendered pixel data, there’s QWidget::render though which you can use to render into a QImage: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render-1

Answer (score 2):

`QImage` is the thing you are looking for. You must use a `QLabel` and add your `QImage` in it, using the `setPixmap` method :

```
QImage myImage;
QLabel myLabel;
myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. QLabel is used like a QWidget, but you can still access the raw pixmap of it.

Comment: If you had seen comments, You wouldn't post this answer, This isn't what I want. I don't want to involve several widgets to get access to a data, user of my application can (must of the time "must") change the widget size, accessing pixels are very easy in X and GDI+, but I want to have a easy cross plat form code

Comment: QLabel **is** a QWidget. See the inheritance diagram.